# Jscrollpane reseting to initial position after alt+tab

Tags: jquery, focus, jscrollpane

I made a fullscreen scroll webste with jScrollpane, it's all working well, but when I try to scroll with a external link and change from browser window to another one, when I come back to it, jscrollpane goes back to initial position!
I have no idea whats wrong but here is how I made it, maintainPosition didn't solved my problem, it seems something with focus action, but I didn't find anything about it!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    w = $(window).width();
    h = $(window).height();
    $('.fullContent').css('width', w);
    $('.fullContent').css('height', h).find('.bg, .lente').css('height', h);
    $('.fullContent').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 30,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 30,
        horizontalDragMinWidth: 161,
        horizontalDragMaxWidth: 161,
        maintainPosition: true,
        animateScroll: true,
        hijackInternalLinks: true
    }).bind('jsp-scroll-x', function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight){
        $('.lente').css('left', scrollPositionX*0.6);
        //console.log('Bg = '+scrollPositionX, 'Lente = '+scrollPositionX*0.6);
    });
    var throttleTimeout;
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){
        w = $(window).height();
        h = $(window).height();
        $('.fullContent').css('width', w);
        $('.fullContent').css('height', h).find('.bg, .lente').css('height', h);
        if($.browser.msie) {
            if(!throttleTimeout) {
                throttleTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.fullContent').data('jsp').reinitialise();
                    throttleTimeout = null;
                },50);
            }
        }else{
            $('.fullContent').data('jsp').reinitialise();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented the line 908, function initFocusHandler, and it stopped doing this anoying thing!

```
        function initFocusHandler()
        {console.log(30)
            pane.find(':input,a').unbind('focus.jsp').bind(
                'focus.jsp',
                function(e)
                {
                    //comment here \/
                    //scrollToElement(e.target, false);
                }
            );
        }
```